# Audioless video accessibility and autoplay/loop

Tags: html, html5-video, accessibility, wcag

I have an audioless video implemented using HTML5's `<video>` tag. I'm trying to find out if auto-playing the video and automatically looping it (assuming I add a button to remove loop as well) would cause accessibility issues? I know there are rules regarding audio as well as video with audio that prevent you from doing that, so I'm also wondering if this video is practically considered a GIF.

The video can be found here for reference:
http://www.med.uottawa.ca/bmi/eng/lee.html

Answer (score 1):

This is technically an accessibility violation if it plays for more than 5 seconds. It affects users with disabilities such as attention deficit disorder. You need to provide a button to stop the video from playing immediately, not only a button that disables the automatic loop.